# R, getting an invalid argument to unary operator when using order function

Tags: r

I'm essentially doing the exact same thing 3 times, and when adding a new variable I get this error

```
Error in -emps$EV : invalid argument to unary operator
```

The code chunk causing this is

```
evps<-aggregate(EV~player,s1k,mean)
sort2<-evps[order(-evps$EV),]
head(sort2,10)

s1k$EM<-s1k$points-s1k$EV
emps<-aggregate(EM~player,s1k,mean)
sort3<-emps[order(-emps$EV),]
head(sort3,10)
```

Works like a charm for the first list, but the identical code thereafter causes the error.

This specific line is causing the error

```
sort3<-emps[order(-emps$EV),]
```

How can I fix/workaround this?

Full Code

```
url <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/M-ttM/Basketball/master/class.csv")
shots <- read.csv(text = url)
shots$make<-shots$points>0
shots2<-shots[which(!(shots$player=="Luc Richard Mbah a Moute")),]
fit1<-glm(make~factor(type)+factor(period), data=shots2,family="binomial")
summary(fit1)
shots2$makeodds<-fitted(fit1)
shots2$EV<-shots2$makeodds*ifelse(shots2$type=="3pt",3,2)
shots3<-shots2[which(shots2$y>7),]
locmakes<-data.frame(table(shots3[, c("x", "y")]))

s1k <- shots2[with(shots2, player %in% names(which(table(player)>=1000))), ]

pps<-aggregate(points~player,s1k,mean)
sort<-pps[order(-PPS$points),]
head(sort,10)

evps<-aggregate(EV~player,s1k,mean)
sort2<-evps[order(-evps$EV),]
head(sort2,10)

s1k$EM<-s1k$points-s1k$EV
emps<-aggregate(EM~player,s1k,mean)
sort3<-emps[order(-emps$EV),]
head(sort3,10)
```

Comment: Can you please include a reproducible example?

Comment: Updated with the whole code

Comment: seems like you meant emps$EM not emps$EV, otherwise you'll probably need to adapt EV and add it to your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line, `emps$EV` doesn't exist.

```
s1k$EM<-s1k$points-s1k$EV
emps<-aggregate(EM~player,s1k,mean)
sort3<-emps[order(-emps$EV),]
head(sort3,10)
```

You probably meant

```
s1k$EM<-s1k$points-s1k$EV
emps<-aggregate(EM~player,s1k,mean)
sort3<-emps[order(-emps$EM),]
head(sort3,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to occur when trying to order columns including `chr` type data. A possible workaround is to use the reverse function `rev()` instead of the minus sign, like so:

```
column_a = c("a","a","b","b","c","c")
column_b = seq(6)
df = data.frame(column_a, column_b)
df$column_a = as.character(df$column_a)

df[with(df, order(-column_a, column_b)),]
> Error in -column_a : invalid argument to unary operator

df[with(df, order(rev(column_a), column_b)),]
  column_a column_b
5        c        5
6        c        6
3        b        3
4        b        4
1        a        1
2        a        2
```

Let me know if it works in your case.

Comment: Caught the same error when trying to reverse order a character type. Why does order() documentation still cite character type as an option for data types that can be ordered?